# Receive a socket emit from client using Express Routes

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sockets, socket.io

I am able to emit and receive messages using socket.io between server and client correctly using the following code on `server.js`.

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 4000
var http = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var args = {class: "one"};

io.of('/programs').on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('joinRoom', (room) => {
        socket.join(room);
        console.log("New Client joined room: " + room);
    });
    socket.emit('welcome', args)
    socket.on('welcome', (data) => {
        console.log('Got result:', data);
    });
});
```

Data is being received properly here. Now I want to use an Express route so that whenever I hit the route, it should emit on `welcome` so that client captures and returns the data. To do this, I made the following changes:

```
const express = require('express')
    const app = express()
    const port = 4000
    var http = require('http').createServer(app);
    var io = require('socket.io')(http);
    var args = {class: "one"};
    
    io.of('/programs').on('connection', function (socket) {
        socket.on('joinRoom', (room) => {
            socket.join(room);
            console.log("New Client joined room: " + room);
        });
    });
    app.get('/', (req, res) => {
        io.of('/programs').to('apps').emit('welcome', args);
        // Receive data emitted by client
        // res.send(data)    
    });
```

Here `apps` is the room. The first line in `app.get` works but I cannot figure out how to receive data without `socket` as I did before, without reopening the connection each time the route is called. Is it even possible?

Comment: Are there multiple clients that should reply data or is there a specific one/the same data (in which case you can save a reference)? If there are multiple responses, you would need to give each response an id, collect all responses for that request and then send them out (quite hard and also error prone)

Comment: There is one client right now. However since I'm passing args, the response will change each time when client is hit.

Comment: @aksayks, The reason I asked whether there was one client was if you could store the socket.io client in a global variable and then access it through that.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I believe that if you received the `join` event, you can receive the `welcome` one same way.

```js
const express = require('express')
    const app = express()
    const port = 4000
    var http = require('http').createServer(app);
    var io = require('socket.io')(http);
    var args = {class: "one"};
    
    io.of('/programs').on('connection', function (socket) {
        socket.on('joinRoom', (room) => {
            socket.join(room);
            console.log("New Client joined room: " + room);
        });
        socket.on('welcome', (data) => {
            console.log('Got result:', data);
        });
    });
    app.get('/', (req, res) => {
        io.of('/programs').to('apps').emit('welcome', args);
        // Receive data emitted by client
        // res.send(data)    
    });
```

In fact thas is exactly what I'm doing today, but my problem is that I can't get an `ack` since inside the express Route I'm broadcasting to a room.

OBS: I'm using version 4.5 of socket.io package